# Where was this flag flown?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military, flags

I have a 48 Star flag that I have recently acquired from a seller off of a similar setting to Craigslist. He said he’s found it in an attic and really has no other information on it. Because the size is near 4 ft x 9ft, and it is truly tattered, I believe it had been flown somewhere other than in front of an average home. I have come to believe it could have flown on a ship from the mounting holes (as shown in the picture), they are very thick and sturdy galvanized eyelets to keep the metal from rusting. These eyelets are very different than those of a “normal flags” folded-over fabric with a grommet in it. Is it possible this flag could’ve been flown on an American ship? Or is it just an oversized home flag? In closing THIS FLAG IS MASSIVE!      [image: (These are the eyelets)]

Comment: By 4x9, do you mean feet? Best clarify this, and state in metric also for non-US/UK readers.

Answer (score 3):

48 Star Flags were flown from July 4th 1912 when New Mexico(1911) and Arizona were added to the Union until July 4th 1960 when Alaska(1959) and Hawaii became states.  By law the flag changes on the subsequent 4th of July following a state's addition to the Union.

So given the dates that means your flag could have flown during The American invasion of Mexico in 1914, WWI, WWII or Korea.   Or of course on somebody's front porch during that time period.

Comment: I don't believe the question is actually answerable, but this does not actually answer it.